# Library for calculating gamma index? (Preferrably in R or Python, but any language is OK)

Tags: python, r, matlab, physics, scientific-computing

In physics--especially medical physics--the gamma index is a criterion for comparing data from two particle detectors. More abstractly, the gamma index takes two 2D arrays (let's say array1 and array2) and compares each element of array1 with spatially-nearby elements of array2.

There are hundreds of academic papers that use the gamma index in their analysis sections. These papers don't seem to mention what tools/libraries they use to calculate the gamma index. It's possible the authors implement their own gamma index calculations (it's not that hard). However, I'm guessing that there are libraries/extensions/tools for calculating a gamma index.

Can anyone suggest a gamma index library to use in R or Python? (Other languages would be ok if there's nothing off-the-shelf for Python or R.)

Comment: Google turns up http://code.google.com/p/pysal/source/browse/trunk/pysal/esda/gamma.py, part of http://code.google.com/p/pysal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found basic MATLAB implementation of the 2D gamma index in Appendix A of [this thesis](http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=2157079&fileOId=2157392&ei=8v0OUMmEOObciQKe74GQAw&usg=AFQjCNHasnzblr2ERawjn5gciGfdSxTDWw&sig2=24WCbX6o4kjKeFO9iu3WFw).

I copy/pasted the following code from the thesis, and I made a couple of simplifications for readability. I talked to the author and confirmed that my version of the code (below) is correct. Recently, I have been using this code in the analysis portion of a medical physics study that I'll be publishing soon.

The inputs `A1` and `A2` are 2D arrays (which, in practice, are dose maps or fluence maps). We let `A1` serve as the reference data, and `A2` is the data that is being evaluated. If we use a typical 2%, 2mm acceptance criterion, then we set distance to agreement as `DTA=2mm`, and we set the dose threshold `dosed=0.02`, which is 2%.

In this simple implementation, we assume that the array indices are spaced in 1mm increments. If your data doesn't use 1mm increments, then scale your `dosed` value accordingly (e.g. if your `A1` and `A2` are in 0.5mm increments, then use `DTA=4` to get a 2mm criterion).

The output, `G`, is a 2D array of gamma values.

```
function G = gamma2d (A1, A2, DTA, dosed)
    size1=size (A1) ;
    size2=size (A2) ;
    dosed = dosed *  max(A1 ( : ) ) ; %scale dosed as a percent of the maximum dose

    G=zeros ( size1 ) ; %this will be the output
    Ga=zeros ( size1 ) ;
    if size1 == size2
        for i = 1 : size1( 1 )
            for j = 1 : size1( 2 )
                for k = 1 : size1( 1 )
                    for l = 1 : size1( 2 )
                        r2 = ( i - k )^2 + (j - l) ^2 ; %distance (radius) squared
                        d2 = ( A1( i , j ) - A2( k , l ) )^2 ; %difference squared
                        Ga( k , l ) = sqrt(r2 / (DTA^2) + d2/ dosed ^ 2);
                    end
                end
                G( i , j )=min(min(Ga)) ;
            end
        end
    else
        fprintf=('matrices A1 and A2 are do not share the same dimensions! \n')
    end
end
```

To see an explanation of the gamma index in math notation, I recommend looking at [this blog post](http://medphys365.blogspot.com/2012/05/comparing-dose-distributions-gamma-test.html).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late but my contribution:

https://gist.github.com/janpipek/334c2533b87cd75c3f59

It is written in Python. In comparison to solvingPuzzles's answer, the methods accept matrices of any dimensionality (provided they are same). There are two methods included: one that calculates gamma index for each point (a bit lengthy) and an optimized version that 
automatically rules out points that don't satisfy dta criterion.

Hope it may be of some help to latecomers.

Comment: Changed into an independent python library: https://github.com/janpipek/gamma_index

Comment: Ha. I'll look at it later maybe but... I was surprised by the Geant4+Python stuff you have at your GitHub page :-) That's what I will investigate.

Comment: The Geant4 python example I have is primarily for people to whet their appetite. Wanted to "lower the barrier of entry" for people who want to experiment. Unfortunately I haven't managed to put much more into it. If you do find it useful, let me know, might work up the motivation to make more of it :)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT [2019]:

An improved 1D, 2D, and 3D Gamma determination is now available within the [`pymedphys` library](https://dos.pymedphys.com). It is based upon the implementation described at https://doi.org/10.1118/1.2721657. To use it, do the following:

```sh
pip install numpy scipy pymedphys==0.16.3 pydicom==1.3.0
```

Then example usage can be as so:

```py
import pydicom
import pymedphys

reference_filepath = pymedphys.data_path("original_dose_beam_4.dcm")
evaluation_filepath = pymedphys.data_path("logfile_dose_beam_4.dcm")

reference = pydicom.read_file(str(reference_filepath), force=True)
evaluation = pydicom.read_file(str(evaluation_filepath), force=True)

axes_reference, dose_reference = pymedphys.dicom.zyx_and_dose_from_dataset(reference)
axes_evaluation, dose_evaluation = pymedphys.dicom.zyx_and_dose_from_dataset(evaluation)

gamma_options = {
    'dose_percent_threshold': 1,  # This is a bit overkill here at 1%/1mm
    'distance_mm_threshold': 1,
    'lower_percent_dose_cutoff': 20,
    'interp_fraction': 10,  # Should be 10 or more, see the paper referenced above
    'max_gamma': 2,
    'random_subset': None,  # Can be used to get quick pass rates
    'local_gamma': True,  # Change to false for global gamma
    'ram_available': 2**29  # 1/2 GB
}

gamma = pymedphys.gamma(
    axes_reference, dose_reference, 
    axes_evaluation, dose_evaluation, 
    **gamma_options)
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

There is a library `npgamma`. Can be downloaded from pypi using `pip install npgamma`.

See the [readme](https://github.com/SimonBiggs/npgamma/blob/master/README.md) for examples.

Basic usage is:

```
from npgamma import calc_gamma

...

gamma = calc_gamma(
    coords_reference, dose_reference,
    coords_evaluation, dose_evaluation,
    distance_threshold, dose_threshold)
```

Where `coords_reference` and `coords_evalution` are defined as (y, x, z) for 3D, (y, x) for 2D.

Importantly, this method interpolates between the reference points down to a user defined step size (defaults to 1/10th of the distance threshold).